# jspm bundle-sfx works on my local machine but not on the build machine

Tags: jspm

At the end of my build process I call:
    jspm bundle-sfx --minify app/app dist/app/app-bundle.js

This has worked fine in the past and is still working on my local machine but is throwing this error on my build server:
    [image: picture of error]

process@0.11.0.js is a dependency of some packages I am using.

I have deleted and reinstalled all my npm and jspm packages a couple of times but still get this error.  Any ideas on other ways to try to get this working again would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting line two of process@0.11.9.js fixed it. Now to figure out why that line was there in the first place...